# Vulnerability in canon printers

Tags: tls, printers

Canon 5035 MFP, Canon 5240i MFP, and Canon 5250 MFP shows the below vulnerabilities. How can we fix this? Couldn't find any option in settings to disable TLS.

```
SSL/TLS Server supports TLSv1.0

Birthday attacks against TLS ciphers with 64bit block size vulnerability (Sweet32)
```

Answer (score 5):

Sweet32 is probably not a problem for common usage of a printer. To cite from [Sweet32: Birthday attacks on 64-bit block ciphers..](https://sweet32.info/):

> We show that a network attacker who can monitor a **long-lived** Triple-DES HTTPS connection between a web browser and a website can recover secure HTTP cookies by **capturing around 785 GB of traffic**.

It is very unlikely that such amount of data will be transferred within a single long-lived HTTPS connection to the printer.

> Couldnt find any option in settings to disable TLS .

Using a plain connection to the printer (i.e. HTTP over TLS (HTTPS) vs. HTTP) is even less secure than using TLS 1.0. If you mean instead that the use of  TLS 1.0 vs. TLS 1.2 is a problem when using the printer (unlikely for most use cases) then you should contact your vendor and check for firmware updates.